# ICEfaces ace:fileEntry not working in Liferay portlet. Have a clue that needs explaining

Tags: file-upload, liferay-6, icefaces-3

Using LR 6.1.0-ce-ga1 and ICEfaces 3.2.0. Have this code in my xhtml:

```
    <ace:panel>
    <ace:fileEntry 
        required="true"
        requiredMessage="You may not save if you have not selected a file."
        fileEntryListener="#{profileBean.listener}"
        maxFileCount="1"
        maxFileCountMessage="Select one file, please."
        useSessionSubdir="true"
        immediate="true"
        />
</ace:panel>
```

First, the immediate doesn't work. listener in my bean never gets called. But that's maybe not as important as the following.

I have h:commandButton on the form. When I click it, I see what looks like the beginning of a progress bar drawn like it's going to display file upload progress. This is immediately covered by the following:
[image: User Session Expired]

This box is often associated with ICEfaces push problems (I've been told by ICEfaces). I added icepush.jar to WEB-INF/lib, but it didn't help. What I'd prefer is not to have the alleged progress bar try to render at all.

So, would appreciate anyone's help in making this file upload work.

P.S., I've tried Tomahawk and plain Apache JSF 2.0, also. I'd like to get the ICEfaces version working, but I'm kind of open to any working solution, given my (Servlet 2.5-based) environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you look at the source code for the [icefaces3-portlet](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/demos#icefaces3-portlet) demo, as it shows how to upload a file with ace:fileEntry in a portlet environment.

Comment: Neil, this portlet seems to be gone from GitHub. Do you have any other examples including Liferay Faces Bridge and ICEfaces3?

Comment: Sorry -- switch to the 3.1.x branch in GitHub and you will see it. The master branch is currently designed for JSF 2.2 which will require ICEfaces 3.4, neither of which has been released yet (at the time of this writing).